# Zapier - Slice not a valid function?

Tags: javascript, bots, zapier

I am still very much a beginner and having issues with the below section. Currently using Zapier in order to take the inputData and split it into the 3 different calculations before combining them and spitting that result back out again.

1st digit, 2nd & 3rd digit and the last 3 are all handled separately as below.

The error I'm getting is that .slice is not a valid function. Hope someone can help :)

```
var inputData = '123456'

// Convert to ABC
var codeA= parseInt(inputData[0], 10) * 60 * 1000;
var codeB = parseInt(inputData.slice(1,3), 10) * 1000;
var codeC = parseInt(inputData.slice(3,6), 10);
```

Comment: When you say: "Currently using Zapier in order to take the inputData", do you mean that you don't really execute your 1st line code, I mean `var inputData = '123456'`?

Comment: Yes, was using it for testing purposes and included it here to be able to run fully.

Comment: Your code is running perfectly fine here. @James' answer may be useful

Comment: You may try `console.log(inputData)` and browse the result in your browser

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn gave me the answer. I used substr instead of slice to fix it. Now i'm just struggling with the format of my inputData though. Zapier states that it gets fed in as a string but i'm getting errors if not converting it. Getting NaN errors if I do convert though.

Comment: Don't forget to validate @Get Off My Lawn's answer; good luck for other errors:)

Comment: I did do so and my bot is 100% working now. Checked Zapier documentation regarding their input and found the problem. I was using "inputData" as the variable which they treat slightly differently.

Comment: For anyone else checking this in the future - `inputData` is an object. The keys and values that exist depend on how the user set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) where there first parameter is the start position and the second parameter is the length:

```js
var inputData = '123456'

// Convert to ABC
var codeA= parseInt(inputData[0], 10) * 60 * 1000;
var codeB = parseInt(inputData.substr(1,2), 10) * 1000;
var codeC = parseInt(inputData.substr(3,3), 10);

console.log(codeA)
console.log(codeB)
console.log(codeC)
```

Comment: I'm still getting inputData.substr is not a function Edit: Figured out why, I had changed my input to Int and not a String. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

.slice is not available for all browsers and types,  .slice is currently available for array, string and blob.  You code appears to work fine locally for me.  Either you are using a browser that doesn't currently support slice for strings which is possible if you are using a really old version of a browser but every major latest browser should support it.  Or you are using some sort of library that is overriding the .slice for strings and such.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice#Browser_compatibility